# How does Bundler utilize Gemfile.lock to load gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'm a bit confused at the moment as to how bundler handles the files Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.

Inside my Gemfile, I have the following

```
group :development do
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
end
```

And on production, I run `bundle install --without development`. However, in Gemfile.lock, 'ruby-debug19' is still listed under DEPENDENCIES at the bottom of the file, and the gem and what it needs are listed in the main listings above.

What is the --without option really doing then? I don't have the necessary gems for ruby-debug19 installed on production, because well, it's production.

I'm fairly new to Rails, and I'm working with v3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the [Bundler FAQ](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) . Your question seems to be answered in the [FAQs](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html)

[FAQ: Why Is Bundler Downloading Gems From --without Groups?](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html#faq-3)